# Continuous action on sprite with dynamic components

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, action, sprite

I need to move a sprite using `CCMoveTo` continuously, as chain of actions. However, the sprite itself along with duration need to be changed each iteration. This is single action.

```
id cloudAction = [CCSequence actions:
                      [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:15.0 position:ccp(-spriteCloud.contentSize.width/2, windowSize.height/2)],
                      cloudActionComplete,
                      nil
                      ];
[spriteCloud runAction:cloudAction];
```

`15` seconds, sprite itself, starting position, ending position all need to be changed each time `CCMoveTo` is done. But I'm not sure how effectively re-run this action from `cloudActionComplete` block action. I can't use `CCRepeatForever` due to dynamic nature of my action. Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish such task?

Update:

This is my attempt

```
    id cloudActionComplete = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^(void)
                           {
                               spriteCloud.position = ccp(windowSize.width + spriteCloud.contentSize.width/2, windowSize.height/2);
                               id cloudAction = [CCSequence actions:
                                                 [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:RANDOMRANGE(2, 10) position:ccp(-spriteCloud.contentSize.width/2, windowSize.height/2)],
                                                 cloudActionComplete,
                                                 nil
                                                 ];
                               [spriteCloud runAction:cloudAction];
                           }];

    [spriteCloud runAction:cloudActionComplete];
```

it works only once, I think the problem is in completion action recursion. `cloudActionComplete` is nil.

Comment: for dynamic behavior skip actions, move the node anually by updating position every frame, that way you have full control

Comment: Yea, ended up with scheduling update... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the same block variable inside the block because its not initialized yet. Alternatively you can create a function to move your clouds

```
- (void) moveCloud:(CCSprite*)spriteCloud
{
    spriteCloud.position = ccp(windowSize.width + spriteCloud.contentSize.width/2, windowSize.height/2);
    id cloudAction = [CCSequence actions:
                      [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:RANDOMRANGE(2, 10) position:ccp(-spriteCloud.contentSize.width/2, windowSize.height/2)],
                      [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(moveCloud:)],
                      nil
                      ];

    [spriteCloud runAction:cloudAction];
}
```